# How to make sure cin opened the file properly?

Tags: c++, cout, cin, istream

I have this code :

```
static std :: ifstream s_inF(argv[j]);
std :: cin.rdbuf(s_inF.rdbuf());
```

How can I make sure it opened the file properly and there is no problem ?

I mean I would like to write something like:

```
static std :: ifstream s_inF(argv[j]);
std :: cin.rdbuf(s_inF.rdbuf());
if(.....)
{
  cout << "can not open the file" << endl;
  return 0;
}
...
.....
....
cin.close();
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_open` for this. See here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/

Answer (score 2):

All objects that are subclasses of [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) -- like `s_inF` and `std::cin`, in your case -- have have an [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that returns true if the stream is ready for I/O operations.

That means you can simply test them directly, e.g.:

```
static std::ifstream s_inF(argv[j]);
std::cin.rdbuf(s_inF.rdbuf());
if (!s_inF)
{
  cout << "can not open the file" << endl;
  return 0;
}
// ...
cin.close();
```